# Why returns the $id in Eloquent query boolean?

Tags: laravel, function, eloquent

I have a **controller** in my `Laravel app` that functions as a product **filter**.

- I am trying to **include the `$id`** I got as a route parameter into the **filters query**, but for some reason it's as though it **becomes `boolean`** as soon as I do.
- If I die and **`dump` it before the query**, it returns the **correct value**.

Inside the `query`, all I get is `true`.

I tried **creating an object** by getting the collection **with said `$id`**, and then including it as a function argument instead, but it's the object's properties just returns a **"trying to access property of boolean"** error.

I thought at first that they were somehow being evaluated as boolean, but apparently it is not.

While **I am able to resolve the issue this causes on the front end**, it hardly seems the ideal solution,
and I am quite curious as to **why this might be happening**.

```
public function collection($id)
{
    return Inertia::render('Collection', [
            'products' => Product::query($id)
            ->when(request()->hasAny('length78', 'length34', 'lengthBl', 'lengthS', 'lengthN' ), function ($query, $id) {
                if(request()->input('length78') === "true"){
                    // dd($id);
                    $query->orWhere('length', '=', '7/8');
                }
                if(request()->input('length34') === "true"){
                    $query->orWhere('length', '=', '3/4');
                }
                if(request()->input('lengthBl') === "true"){
                    $query->orWhere('length', '=', 'bicycle length');
                }
                if(request()->input('lengthS') === "true"){
                    $query->orWhere('length', '=', 'short');
                }
                if(request()->input('lengthN') === "true"){
                    $query->orWhere('length', '=', 'normal');
                }
            })
            ->when(request()->hasAny('blue', 'beige', 'grey', 'military', 'pink', 'black'), function ($query, $id) {
                if(request()->input('blue') === "true"){
                    $query->orWhere('color', '=', 'blue');
                }
                if(request()->input('beige') === "true"){
                    $query->orWhere('color', '=', 'beige');
                }
                if(request()->input('grey') === "true"){
                    $query->orWhere('color', '=', 'grey');
                }
                if(request()->input('military') === "true"){
                    $query->orWhere('color', '=', 'military');
                }
                if(request()->input('pink') === "true"){
                    $query->orWhere('color', '=', 'pink');
                }
                if(request()->input('black') === "true"){
                    $query->orWhere('color', '=', 'black');
                }

            })
                ->when(request()->has('vMin'), function ($query, $id) {

                    $query->where('price', '>=', request()->input('vMin'));

                })
                ->when(request()->has('vMax'), function ($query, $id) {

                    $query->where('price', '<=', request()->input('vMax'));

                })
        
               // ->orWhere('collection_id', '=', $id)
            ->paginate(10)
            ->withQueryString()
            ->through(fn($product) => [
                'id' => $product->id,
                'name' => $product->name,
                'size' => $product->size,
                'waist' => $product->size,
                'price' => $product->price,
                'collection_id' => $product->collection_id,
                'description' => $product->description
            ]),
        'filters' => (new \Illuminate\Http\Request)->only([
            'sizeXxs', 'sizeXs', 'sizeS', 'sizeM', 'sizeL', 'sizeXl', 'filters',
            'waistM', 'waistH', 'waistHi', 'collection',
            'length78', 'length34', 'lengthBl', 'lengthS', 'lengthN',
            'vMin', 'vMax',
            'blue', 'beige', 'grey', 'military', 'pink', 'black'
        ])

    ]);


}
```

Comment: I am so confused, your issue is that you are getting `$id` as `boolean` inside a function? if that is the case, why are you using `::query($id)`? `query()` accepts NO argument, so it is doing nothing at all. You need to point us exactly where it is not working. I do see a commented `dd`, but still, this is a lot of code, you need to be more exact/explicit

Comment: Hi  @vStubbs did you check if you do an unintended typecast somewhere? Any value different from 0 is "true".

Comment: I just want the id data from the controller inside the function. I guess the query accepting no arguments answers that. Still curious as to why exactly this is happening though, but I'm fairly confident no typecasting was involved.

I was able to come up with a better solution by passing the value as a prop which I can access from the queries, so all's well.

Answer (score 1):

In several places you have written

`->when(request()->hasAny('...' ), function ($query, $id) {...`

By defining the `$id` as the second argument of the callback it gets the value of the `when` condition meaning `request()->hasAny('...' )` which returns boolean.

What you probably meant to do is

`->when(request()->hasAny('...' ), function ($query) use ($id) {...`

Notice the difference in function params and `use`. Conditional clauses are documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#conditional-clauses).

Also as it was already noted by another user `Product::query($id)` does not take any arguments, meaning it should be `Product::query()` or `Product::query()->whereKey($id)` depends on what you want to achieve.